Redirect link from search or category to an existing page to show results with filters
I have a listings website main page and i want :

when the user clicks on a category to redirect him to an existing page that shows list of the listings but with that specific category (eg when i click oil category open the page and show the results from the oil category)

<div class="main_categories">
 <div class="container">
                <ul class="clearfix">
                    <li>
                        <a href="grid-listings-filterscol.html">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-bottle-droplet"></i>
                            <h3>Λάδι</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="grid-listings-filterscol.html">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-apple-whole"></i>
                            <h3>Φρούτα</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="grid-listings-filterscol.html">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-seedling"></i>
                            <h3>Λαχανικά</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="grid-listings-filterscol.html">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-jar"></i>
                            <h3>Μέλι</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="grid-listings-filterscol.html">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></i>
                            <h3>Περισσότερα</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /container -->
        </div>


Same with search bar --> show results to the list page with the filters already selected

<section class="hero_single version_2">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <h3>ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΑ ΠΡΟΙΟΝΤΑ</h3>
                    <p>Ανακάλυψε τους καλύτερους παραγωγούς φυσικών προιόντων στην Ελλάδα.</p>
                    <form method="post" action="grid-listings-isotope.html">
                        <div class="row g-0 custom-search-input-2">
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Τι ψάχνεις...">
                                    <i class="icon_search"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select class="wide">
                                        <option>Όλες οι περιοχές</option>   
                                        <option>Αττική</option>
                                        <option>Πελοπόννησος</option>
                                        <option>Στερεά Ελλάδα</option>
                                        <option>Κρήτη</option>
                                        <option>Βόρεια Ελλάδα</option>
                                        <option>Νησιά Αιγαίου</option>
                                        <option>Νησιά Ιονίου</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <select class="wide">
                                    <option>Όλες οι κατηγορίες</option> 
                                    <option>Λάδι</option>
                                    <option>Φρούτα</option>
                                    <option>Λαχανικά</option>
                                    <option>Μέλι</option>
                                    <option>Ζωοτροφές</option>
                                    <option>Βιολογικά</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <input type="submit" value="Αναζήτηση">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /row -->
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

Is it possible to achieve this with Javascript - Jquery?
Thank you in advance
I have this on the list page and it works but i don't know how to connect 2 pages
<script>$(window).on('load', function(){var $container = $('.isotope-wrapper');$container.isotope({ itemSelector: '.isotope-item', layoutMode: 'masonry' });});

$('.category_filter').on( 'click', 'input', 'change', function(){   var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');   $('.isotope-wrapper').isotope({ filter: selector });  }); $('.city_filter').on('click', 'input', 'change', function(){   var selector = $(this).attr('location-filter');   $('.isotope-wrapper').isotope({ filter: selector }); }); </script> <script>   $('.filters_listing').on( 'click', 'input', 'change', function(){   var selector = $(this).attr('popular-filter');   $('.isotope-wrapper').isotope({ filter: selector }); }); </script>


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Do you have a database on the backend where you store info about you items and categories, or are you planning just to have static HTML pages with all the listings?

@chrwahl i am planning to have static HTML pages

you can achieve this by using searchParams
<a href="grid-listings-filterscol.html?categoryId=3"> // add categoryId or name here
  <i class="fa-solid fa-bottle-droplet"></i>
  <h3>Λάδι</h3>
</a>
}

then in grid-listings-filterscol.html page you can get id by using javascript location object
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
const categoryId = urlParams.get('categoryId') // retrieve categoryId from params

/// process categoryId here


now when the user does a search and click on search button, you add a params to url too
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Τι ψάχνεις...">
    <i class="icon_search" onclick="makeSearch"></i> // add onclick event here
</div>
</div>

const makeSearch = () => {
  const searchInput = document.querySelector('.form-control')

  /// do something with searchInput.value
}

